# Orientation of instances in Particles Instance Modifier

Tags: hair, instances

I'm trying to get dynamic tassels attached to the end of a scarf in the example here. 
[image: _particle_instance_mod_problem]

I just don't seem to be able to get the tassels oriented correctly, despite having studied 
[Samir's excellent explanation here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51259/how-can-i-use-hair-dynamics-with-instanced-geometry-and-have-it-deform-like-hair/81399#81399)

[here is a link to the blend in question](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j99npor2nn0tmn0/scarf_17.blend?dl=0)

Many thanks in advance,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Tassle_twist.001 has a particle system applied to it from the Modifiers tab. That does'n seem right. remove it, then select the belt and from the particles tab section Render select Object instead of Path and select Tassle_twist.001 as Dupli Object. Now go to the Physics section of the Particles tab and set the size to 1. It's not entirely clear to me what you want or what you're having trouble with exactly, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer coCoKNIght, I was trying to use the technique described in this post:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51259/how-can-i-use-hair-dynamics-with-instanced-geometry-and-have-it-deform-like-hair